# All test cases passed except one which is throwing key error

Tags: python-3.x, graph

We are given a directed graph, with nodes labeled 0, 1, ..., n-1 and each edge is either red or blue, and there could be self-edges or parallel edges.

Each [i, j] in red_edges denotes a red directed edge from node i to node j.  Similarly, for blue_edges.

Return an array 'answer' of length n, where each answer[X] is the length of the shortest path from node 0 to node X such that the edge colors alternate along the path (or -1 if such a path doesn't exist).

I'm not getting where's the problem in the code.

1. n = 3, red_edges = [[0,1],[1,2]], blue_edges = []
2. n = 3, red_edges = [[0,1]], blue_edges = [[2,1]]
3. n = 3, red_edges = [[0,1]], blue_edges = [[1,2]]
4. n = 3, red_edges = [[1,0]], blue_edges = [[2,1]]

```py
     d={}
    result=[-1]*(n)
    for i in red_edges:
        if i[0] not in d:
            d[i[0]]=[i[1]]
        else:
            d[i[0]].append(i[1])
        if i[0]==0:
            result[i[1]]=1
     #print(d)
    for j in blue_edges:
        if j[0] not in d:    
            d[j[0]]=[j[1]]            
        else:
            d[j[0]].append(j[1])
        if j[0]==0:
            result[j[1]]=1
        elif j[0]!=0:
            if j[0] in d[0]: #This is Line 24 which is throwing error. 
                result[j[1]]=2
            else:
                pass
        if 0 in d[0]:
            result[0]=1
        else:
            result[0]=0

        #print(d)
        print(result)
```

Key in 'd' is equal to the starting node and value in a key-value pair has a list in which all the endpoints corresponding to that key are inserted.
Moreover, in each for loop, I'm also preparing my result array if any edge is present between node zero and node equal to the index of the result array. e.g, I'll insert 1 in result array for index 1 if it has a direct link with node zero else I'll keep it as -1. And if any index has indirect link( as in test case 2: blue_edges =[[2,1]]) then I'll check in d[0] if first element of blue_edges is present. If it is present then I'll insert 2 else -1.

1. expected=actual=[0,1,-1]
2. expected=actual=[0,1,-1]
3. expected=actual=[0,1,1]
4. expected=[0,-1,-1] but in 4th case it is throwing an error. 
   Line 24: KeyError: 0

Comment: could you elaborate on algorithm a little? e.g. what does `d` map? (from what to what, logically).

Comment: for test case 3, why isn't it `[0,1,2]`..?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 it is clearly written in the problem above that both the arrays will only contain start point and the endpoint of any edge. so, [0,1,2] is not the valid test case. By the way, I've explained my intuition above. you can check it.

Comment: I meant in the answer. I think the shortest path to node 2 is 2, not 1.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 yes! it is [0,1,2] and I'm also getting that output.

Comment: OK, great, I've added an attempted answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57131356/5052365), I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to using [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) so that if `d` is empty for some value, you'll just get an empty list.

In your case - it eliminates the error and logically matches the `if`.

it also help clean up many `if/else`s.

try this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

cases = [
    (3, [[0, 1], [1, 2]], []),
    (3, [[0, 1]], [[2, 1]]),
    (3, [[0, 1]], [[1, 2]]),
    (3, [[1, 0]], [[2, 1]]),
]

for n, red_edges, blue_edges in cases:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    result = [-1] * n
    result[0] = 0

    for src, dst in red_edges:
        d[src].append(dst)
        if src == 0:
            result[dst] = 1

    for src, dst in blue_edges:
        d[src].append(dst)
        if src == 0:
            result[dst] = 1
        else:
            if src in d[0]:
                result[dst] = 2

    print(result)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, -1]
[0, 1, -1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, -1, -1]
```